# How to do floating conversions in scheme (drracket)?

Tags: binary, hex, scheme, racket, octal

I want to do some conversions of bin to hex , hex to bin, hex to dec etc in scheme language. but I'm not used to drracket like an advanced user. I need to implement 3x4 as all possible pairs of binary, hexadecimal, octal and decimal.

So far I only accomplished to implement bin to dec but I didn't handle the idea of the others, can anyone give me some tips, idea or code blocks and all kind of helps to improve my implementation?

I placed my bin to dec below, thank you all in advance.

```
(define (bin-to-dec x)
  (if (zero? x)
      x
      (+ (modulo x 10) (* 2 (bin->dec (quotient x 10))))))
```

Have a nice day, keep safe.

Comment: What is wrong with the built-in Racket [`number->string`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=number-%3Estring#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._number-~3estring%29%29) procedure? E.g. `(number->string #b11111 16)`  ==>  `"1f"`.

Comment: Numbers are numbers, they do not have a base. It looks like your input to that function is a number that is written with only ones and zeros in the decimal system, but that's not a binary number.

Comment: I want to implement higher order procedure. How can I do those as higher order? @molbdnilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second you have a fixnum (integer) in Scheme the base is not important as the number does not have a base. The reason is that base is related to visual encoding of a number. Eg. 10 can be written as `#b1010` `#xa` `#o12` and all of these will in a Scheme repl display `10` since the repl shows the number representations in decimal:

```scm
#b1010 ; ==> 10
#xa    ; ==> 10
#o12   ; ==> 10
```

If you want to print a number in a different base you do that when the number goes from a number to a visualized representation (eg. string). Scheme has this with `number->string`

```scm
(number->string 10 2)  ; ==> "1010"
(number->string 10 16) ; ==> "a"
(number->string 10 8)  ; ==> "12"
```

There is also `string->int` that does the reverse:

```scm
(string->number "1010" 2) ; ==> 10
(string->number "a" 16)   ; ==> 10
(string->number "12" 8)   ; ==> 10
```

Your implementation `bin->dec` takes a number of any base as input and transforms its decimal visualization as if it was binary to decimal. eg

```scm
(bin-to-dec #b1010) ; ==> 2
```

Comment: So, these are proper use of floating number conversions. Can I get all inputs of combination of 4x3 part of them? bintodec, bintohex, bintooctal and for the other ones etc. ?

Comment: Basically you want to convert from string to bigger then back to string. You can chain the examples to get it working.

Comment: Is this higher order procedure? if it's not, how can I use it like that?

Comment: @PensarNada higher order procedures is just fancy for a procedure that either takes a procedure as parameter or evaluates to one. Yes, you can make a `make-base-converter` that takes expected input base  and wanted output base and evaluate to a procedure that does that conversion so that you can do this `(define hex->dec (make-base-converter 16 10))`

Comment: Could you give me a higher order procedure by using number->string or string->number ? or can I do " (define hex->dec (conversion-makes 16 10) (string->number n)) " or something like that? is it gonna be higher order? cause I couldn't understand the "make-base-converter" , is it placeholder or proper operator, function or something like that, when I try to run it, it does not defined.

Comment: @PensarNada Basically `(define (make-adder parameter) (lambda (v) (+ parameter v))` only that your takes bases and uses the two prodceures in my answer. Then if I can make `add1` like this `(define add1 (make-adder 1))`

Comment: Somehow I figured it out but I didn't actually get the ```(define (make-adder parameter) (lambda (v) (+ parameter v))``` line, guess I'm not proper to understand that so far :D, So, I'll put here some codes that I accomplished to make conversions but as I said, I do not know those are higher order or not. Thank you for your helps btw, you're a great person. ```(define
  (dec-to-bin n)
  (number->string n 2))
(define
  (dec-to-oct n)
  (number->string n 8))
(define
  (dec-to-hex n)
  (number->string n 16))```

I can do all decimal to * conversions here, it works but ... :))))))

Comment: @PensarNada The whole point is that your `dec-to-bin` and `dec-to-oct` has the exat same code except for one value. You can use the same trick eg. `(define (make-dec-to-base base) (lambda (n) (number->string n base)))` and `(define dec-to-bin  (make-dec-to-base 2))`, `(define dec-to-hex  (make-dec-to-base 16))`. See?

Comment: So, these are count as higher order procedure? just yes or no will be enough, I asked so many questions, sorry about that :D and thank you many many times.

Comment: Yes. `make-adder` and `make-dec-to-base` are [higher order procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) because they return procedures. `map` is also a higher order procedure because it takes a procedure as one of its arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Racket has built-in procedures to handle this sort of thing. [`number->string`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=number-%3Estring#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._number-~3estring%29%29) will take a number and return a string representation in the specified base. If input can be given in the form of a number literal you can do something like:

```
(number->string #b11111 16)  ==>  "1f"
```

If the goal is to convert between string representations, the above can be combined with the built-in [`string->number`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=string-%3Enumber#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3enumber%29%29), e.g.:

```
(define (nstring->nstring nstring radix-in radix-out)
  (number->string (string->number nstring radix-in) radix-out))
```

```
scratch.rkt> (nstring->nstring "11111" 2 16)
"1f"
scratch.rkt> (nstring->nstring "31" 10 2)
"11111"
scratch.rkt> (nstring->nstring "1f" 16 10)
"31"
```

Comment: Can I seperetely define all of them into 12 pieces and put this "number->string" function inside? So, I can call everyone of them to convert what I want specifically like

(define ((bintodec n) 10) ((number->string n)10))